# Navigate to original requested page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have page where are secured by session. In case session does exists, then navigate to login page. This works fine.

Now, Let's say I am at some page like abc.aspx. Session does not exists. System navigates to th login page. So, once login, can i navigate the user to the page which was originally requested ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is performed by adding the requested URL as a query parameter to Login page URL `http://fakehost/Login?retUrl=originalpage`
 so app code can redirect it back. Forms authentication mechanism does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can however it would be recommended to add a ReturnUrl querystring which contains the page they came from or need to go to after they logged in. you can also use Request.UrlReferrer I believe which gives you the page they came from but means if for example they came from google to your site to login and you redirect, it would go back to google.